# How to log into SQL server with System DSN using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, dsn

I'm trying to connect to my Microsoft SQL Express Database using a system DSN and Python. My current code reads this:

```
con_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=SQLExpress;DATABASE=pydb;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
```

How do I change this to work with my DSN (Made with Microsoft ODBC Administrator 64-bit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it here for reference, visit this :

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

and find connection string that suits your DSN

Comment: Specifically the answer was found on https://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn/

Comment: @DARSIN there you go ;)